# How to send the device token and app version to server

Tags: iphone

I have implemented to send the device token and app version to serverm. It was working fine in simulator(hard coded data) but it is not working in device.
Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Here is the code

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {


    // Get Bundle Info for Remote Registration (handy if you have more than one app)
    NSString *appVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

    // Prepare the Device Token for Registration (remove spaces and < >)
    NSString *deviceToken = [[[[devToken description]
                               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                              stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

    NSMutableString *urlString = [[BASE_URL mutableCopy] autorelease];
    [urlString appendFormat:@"traceDeviceTokenId?tokenid=%@&version=%@",deviceToken, appVersion];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [urlString length]];       
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 

    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; 
    [request setValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-16" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[urlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@"Request xml>>>>>> %@", urlString);

    NSError *error; 
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSString *responseXml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response xml>>>>>> = %@", responseXml);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{ 

    NSString *strWithoutSpaces  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
    strWithoutSpaces = [strWithoutSpaces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];    
    strWithoutSpaces = [strWithoutSpaces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    strDeviceToken = [strWithoutSpaces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];

    [self createRequestWithDeviceToken:strDeviceToken];     
}

- (void) createRequestWithDeviceToken:(NSString*)deviceToken
{    
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
        NSString *strURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",APNS_DEVICE_REGISTRATION_URL, deviceToken];
        [self prepareConnectionForWebService:strURL delegateHandler:self];
        [strURL release];

}

- (void) prepareConnectionForWebService:(NSString*)webServiceURL delegateHandler:(id)object
{
    //Create HTTP request
    objRequest = [[RequestCreation alloc] init];
    [self.objRequest initRequestWithURL:webServiceURL withMethodType:@"GET" withContentType:@"text/html" andBodyData:nil];

    //Placing URLConnection with request.
    objConnection = [[[ConnectionCreation alloc]init] autorelease];
    self.objConnection.delegate = object;
    [self.objConnection initWithRequest:self.objRequest.objURLRequest];
    [objRequest release];
}

- (void) initWithRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)requestedURL
{
    self.urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:requestedURL delegate:self];
    if(self.urlConnection)
    {
        receivedData=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
    else 
    {
        //infiorm the user that the connection is failed
        UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Connection Failure" message:@"Unable to connect" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }
}
```

I justed pasted the code which currently running for my application. Just go through the code for understanding where u went wrong. Break the code written in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken in small methods for proper understanding.
Hope this help.