# sending the device token and app version to server

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send the device token and app version to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309742/how-to-send-the-device-token-and-app-version-to-server)

I have implemented the push notification service in my application, But am not able to send the device token id and app version to server.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the my code

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
    // Get Bundle Info for Remote Registration (handy if you have more than one app)
    NSString *appVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
    // Prepare the Device Token for Registration (remove spaces and < >)
    NSString *deviceToken = [[[[devToken description]
                        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
    NSMutableString *urlString = [[BASE_URL mutableCopy] autorelease];
    [urlString appendFormat:@"traceDeviceTokenId?tokenid=%@&version=%@",deviceToken, appVersion];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [urlString length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; 
    [request setValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-16" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[urlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@"Request xml>>>>>> %@", urlString);
    NSError *error; 
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *responseXml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response xml>>>>>> = %@", responseXml);
}
```

Comment: So, what is actually going wrong? Simply saying "doesn't work" won't help anyone. Have you debugged the variable contents, how do you send the variables to your server etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously not sending anything back to the server in the code you provided. To send it to a server you can use SOAP. And to check if the token is the right format, write

```
NSLog(@"%@",deviceToken)
```